# Each time code is run loop should begin in first column on second sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Each time I run the code below, it should begin by pasting the first column in the Import_R sheet to the the first column in Organise_R sheet. For some reason however, each time I start it the code pastes into the column in Organise_R where the previous run left off. I need to somehow tell the code to always start in the first column in the organise_R sheet. I've tried to define b as 1 but clearly that conflicts with line 4? Please help!

```
For a = 1 To 60

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Excel.Sheets("Import_R").Columns(a)) > 0 Then

    Excel.Sheets("Import_R").Columns(a).Copy

   b = Excel.Sheets("Organise_R").UsedRange.Columns.Count

    Excel.Sheets("Organise_R").Select



    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Excel.Sheets("Organise_R").Columns(b)) > 0 Then b = b + 1


        Excel.Sheets("Organise_R").Columns(b).EntireColumn.Select
        Excel.ActiveSheet.Paste

        Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1, b), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
                :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
                Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End If



Next a
```

Comment: Have you considered clearing the contents of Organise_R? Since you apparently want to overwrite them. Just call `Worksheets("Organize_R").Cells.Delete` prior to your for loop.

Comment: @ Daniel Cook - I was hoping to be be giving you a big tick and castigating myself for not thinking of that. I had already cleared the sheet but I hadn't thought of deleting. unfortunately deletion hasn't done it I'm afraid. It seems that the last value of b is being saved until the code is run again.

Comment: @Daniel Cook's suggestion is good but I believe you have to save, close and then re-open the workbook for the UsedRange to reset.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is always supposed to start in the first column of "Organize_R" then why do you use the code below?

```
b = Excel.Sheets("Organise_R").UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

why not

```
Excel.Sheets("Organise_R").ClearContents
b = 1
```

?

Comment: @ Exactabox - Sorry, maybe I'm not being clear.The first column in Import_R sheet will always paste to column A in organise_R. Text to columns is then performed, which usually results in 10 full columns in Ornaise_R. The second column in Import_R will then paste to the the next available column in Organise_R, the 11th column, and the process continues. So I dont want to replace the data I've just put in, I want it to look for the next avialable empty column.At the moment though it starts running where the old run finished.If run finished on column Z, the next run starts on AA, instead of A.

Comment: You can place the line b = 1 before the loop begins.  Then move b = Excel.Sheets("Organise_R").UsedRange.Columns.Count to the last line within the loop, right before "Next a"

Comment: That hasn't done it im afraid. The first loop pasted into column A in the Organise_R sheet as hoped but the second loop was pasted into column OOU. All sheets are cleared at the start of my program and I delete all cells in Organise_R prior to this loop to make sure but b is being stored somewhere from previous runs. Do you know if it is possible to clear the register or something?

Comment: b is not being stored from previous runs.  There is something on your spreadsheet you are not picking up... when you reference "UsedRange," this includes anything, even a blank cell where the font size was once changed.  (As I mentioned above, after deleting columns, you still need to save, close and re-open the file before a new UsedRange is determined.)  Also, since you use the TextToColumns, this can be spilling into dozens/hundreds of columns if you aren't 100% sure of what you are copying over first.  I'm afraid without a sample there's no more help to provide.

Comment: I must be going blind. I overlooked your reference to usedrange the first time round. I went off and 'discovered' that usedrange must not be resetting. Restarting the workbook didn't work. Neither did any of the code I found online that purported to solve the problem. In the end I just deleted and then added the sheet back in. Thanks for the responses and apologies for the delay in replying!